# Where was the film "The Color of Paradise (original Rang-e khoda)" made?

Tags: film-location, the-color-of-paradise

Where was the film [The Color of Paradise](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0191043/) (original Rang-e khoda) made?

I'm interested in which regions of Iran this film was shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [article](http://www.iran-newspaper.com/?nid=6292&pid=3&type=1) It was filmed in [Jokandan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saheli-ye_Jokandan_Rural_District) جوکندان rural district. You can find its location on a map at these coordinates: [37.9, 48.9](https://goo.gl/maps/NCZBm7nqSjC2)